# Executing a JAR on X startup

Tags: linux, executable-jar

I'm trying to setup a kiosk type system in linux where a java application launches when X is initialized.  I've got a script which does the following:

java -cp {correct path to JAR with main method} -jar {name of JAR}

When I've cd'd into the directory where the JAR sits, everything is peaches and the system works like I want, however, if I navigate to any other directory, X terminates and reports that it could not access the JAR.

What am I missing here?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the -cp *and* the -jar

> java -jar {full path}

should work. Your mainifest file in the .jar should then specify the appropriate main() method. See [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) for more details on that.